# How to create SSRS report using 'SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio'

Tags: reporting-services

Please let me know any thread for creating a step by step SSRS report using `SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio`

I'm using `Sql Server 2008` for `Reporting data` my table name is `EmpData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server's books online have tutorials about building reports.

You can also find these tutorial's online [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522859(v=SQL.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522859%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)